# Batch Script "Timeout" Error: Invalid Syntax. Default option is not allowed more than 1 time

Tags: windows, batch-file, timeout

First off, I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, if it makes a difference. I have a batch file in which I'm using the "timeout" function, written as such:

```
*code does some things*
timeout /t 100 rem wait for 100 seconds for the above thing to finish
```

If I do `timeout /t 100` in the command line, it waits for 100 seconds as I would expect. However, in the script it gives me the error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '1' time(s).
Type "TIMEOUT /?" for usage.
```

The instructions for `timeout` are `/t` for number of seconds to wait, `/nobreak` to ignore keypresses, and `/?` to display the help message. I'm not sure what syntactical error I'm having, or what "default option is not allowed", especially since it seems to work perfectly fine outside of the batch file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rem wait for 100 seconds for the above thing to finish
timeout /t 100
```

You cant's set a comment on the same line as the command.

Comment: Oh my... I feel silly not knowing that. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: How can i set timeout with **exec()** in php ?

Answer (score 2):

A comment is another command.  So if you want it on the same line you need to use the & like this.

```
timeout /t 100 & rem wait for 100 seconds for the above thing to finish
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was ending my lines with CRs instead of LFs.

In Notepad++, I replaced all the \r with \n and it now works.